# IronPython compile() does not accept AST object

Tags: parsing, ironpython, abstract-syntax-tree

In the documentation it says, 'source' can be either str or AST object

When trying to compile my ast root:

```
dl = compile(newRoot, '<string>', 'eval')
```

I get this Exception:

```
expected str, got Module
```

I am using the last version of IronPython.

Is there an idea why this does not work? all the examples I found seem to do it this way with no issues.

Is there a workaround to compile an AST object?

Thanks!!!!

PD: I found this issue but seems to have no activity: http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/32526

Comment: Yes, Module is a class of ast node.

Comment: This is definetly a bug in IronPython. Ill have to umparse the AST, convert it to string, and then fed it to compile(). :(

Answer (score 0):

First off, IronPython does not support this.

It's actually quite hard to support in IronPython (and I didn't know it needed to be supported until today). IronPython's `_ast` module is a wrapper around its own AST, and currently only implements conversion from IronPython AST => CPython AST, but not the reverse. It's a fair bit of (honestly, quite tedious) work, so I'm not sure when it will get fixed.

If there's a popular program or library that's broken because of this that moves it up the priority list, and patches are always welcome.

Comment: setuptools seems to use this feature.
https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/f5ac515/_markerlib/markers.py?at=default